# I have a very unstable network connection -- what settings would best fit in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

I get lots of latency variation warnings and my ping spikes up every minute or two for a few seconds -- normally this wouldn't be a problem in most other games but for RL, having a bad connection can be watching a ball move in completely unprecedented ways, leading to a bad time.

The specific settings I'm looking to understand are Server Bandwith, Client Send Rate, Server Send Rate, and the three input buffer options.  What settings are my best bet if my connection is unstable (even with Ethernet) or in general just poor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be mitigated by game settings. You may make a micro improvement by changing some of the performance impacting settings like shading or lighting, but in general I don't think it is possible to even slightly reduce the impact of dropping that many packets.

Even squishy suffers from this type of interruption at times, and he has been through every setting possible.